# insertHTML with onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the onclick attribute into my javascript file that executes insertHTML

Here is how I'd imagined the code to look like:

```
{insertHTML+='<a href="#" class="tl-g-media-button tl-g-video-button" onclick="ga('send', 'event','video', 'click');" videoKey="'+anImage.key+'">'+TLConfigText['contentPanel_Play_video']+'</a>';}
```

But it just ended up with syntax errors.
Here's the original code:

```
{insertHTML+='<a href="#" class="tl-g-media-button tl-g-video-button" videoKey="'+anImage.key+'">'+TLConfigText['contentPanel_Play_video']+'</a>';}
```

Is there anyway for me to get the tracker for Google Analytics into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `'` characters with `\'`:

```
... onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\',\'video\', \'click\');" ...
```